# Conditional template for a row in a table shows warning in editor

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The following table structure does not work:

```dart
<table>
  <tr><td>..</td></tr>
  <tr template if="{{flag==true}}">
<td>optional row</td>
 </tr>
```

If template is moved above a row as follows then code works.

```dart
<table>
  <tr><td>..</td></tr>
  <template if="{{flag==true}}">
    <tr >
  <td>optional row</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

but using template as above shows warning in editor:
Unexpected start tag (template) in table context caused voodoo mode.

Currently I am ignoring the warning as code seems to work, but is it the right way to use template to conditionally display a row of a table?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your second version is the right/preferred/intended (not sure) way to do it.
- Your first version is for browsers that don't support the `<template>` tag. This is the more compatible version.

[Polymer - FAQ - How do I use data-binding to repeat an  or ?](http://www.polymer-project.org/faq.html#option-tr)